# Растянуть картинку не меняя ее пропорции

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Есть баннер, который будет занимать всю высоту и ширину экрана, нужно чтоб он сохранял свои пропорции при любом соотношении сторон монитора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a href="#" class="banner-item">
    <img class="banner-item__bg" src="img/banner_1.jpg" alt="banner">
</a>
```

```
.banner {
  height: 100vh;

  &-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;

    &__bg {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: я не знаю ответа, но кажется просто высоту сделать 100% и ширину уже подгонять под него width: auto;

Comment: такой вариант подойдет?  https://jsfiddle.net/10tjz6Ld/

Comment: "всю высоту и ширину экрана" на разных экранах, сохраняя пропорции не получится. Придётся выбрать - ширину, высоту, или обрезать часть баннера.

Comment: soledar10, спасибо! добавьте ответ и получите лайк)

Comment: @ШкедАскет, это не сработает при всех пропорциях. Можно подобрать размер экрана так, что `width: auto;` окажется уже чем экран.

Answer (score 1):

### Вариант SVG

*Решение адаптивно. Работает во всех браузерах, включая `IE11`, `Edge`*

- Параметры `viewBox="0 0 1365 707"` выбраны равными размерам картинки
  баннера.
- При значениях - `viewport` это `width="100%"` и `height="100%"` в шапке svg холст занимает 100% окна браузера.
- Баннер включен внутри svg с помощью команды `<image .. width="100%"
  height="100%">` поэтому он полностью заполнит весь холст svg.
- svg обернут в контейнер  поэтому вы можете изменять начальные
  размеры блока, изменяя ширину и высоту родительского контейнера.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1365 707" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuXY1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Илья Шишлачев если ответ был полезен, то отметьте его, как верное решение

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuXY1.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner {
  height: 100vh;

  &-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;

    &__bg {
      display: block;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height:100%;
      width:auto;
      height:auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Можно еще выставить max-width и max-height